# Call different servlets based on User input

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

Is this feasible technically?

1. I have a jsp page with a text value and submit button.
2. Single jsp is associated with multiple servlets.
3. User gives value in text value, that is servlet name.
4. Based on that textvalue, the servlet has to be called.

Example

Jsp

servelt name: *** user input***
submit

Servlet1, servlet 2, servlet3 --> associated with jsp (is that first of all doable)

then if user enters: servlet1 as servlet name, then only that servlet has to be called.

Comment: use jquery and ajax

Comment: Why work this way? instead of having 3 servlets, have one and make different businesses(interfaces/functions, whatever). Not in the servlet just switch over the requested business(as you stated servlet name) and call teh related business.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery like @Scary Wombat suggested, it's very helpful.

Click of submit button in your form will have to change action attribute of the form.

You can do something like this:

Note: Servlet resources are unavailable, I used sample names.

```js
$("#submitBtn").click (function () {
alert($("#form1").attr("action")+" before");
$("#form1").attr("action",$("#className").val());
alert($("#form1").attr("action")+" after");
$("#form1").submit();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="Class1">
<input type="text" id="className"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitBtn">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the input.... but I havent worked on Jquery.... I have all ma logics in servlet...can you please explain how i can incorporate that with Jquery

Comment: I was suggesting you put the above logic into your JSP. In the above code what happens is: form tag has action attribute which will take your servlet class. In javascript with the help of jquery, you can replace value of action attribute on click of submit button. In your JSP place javascript snippet into another script tag like <script>$("submitBtn"). I have created a code snippet fully in html in jsfiddle. [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kratostoical/zgxf9xwd/1/) feel free to explore the same. Hope this helps.